# Best way to create a Website/Server with expandable storage

Tags: amazon-ec2, server, cloud, amazon-efs

At the moment I am creating a website where Users can upload files.
It is running on an Apache, php MariaDB root Server with 400GB of Storage.

But as you can imagine, if Users are able to upload files the storage will be full in no time.

What is the common way to setup such environments?

I know there is Amazon EC2 and Elastic File Systems but I would like to know if someone (maybe someone professional) could explain some common alternatives.

So the requirements are: Root Server or VPS (full access to the system is mandatory) and some kind of expandable storage.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use MariaDB to store uploads?

Comment: i use mariadb to store the path, name, extension etc, but the files are stored in folders on the filesystem. I don't store blobs.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping user files on an EC2 instance is **not scalable nor fault tolerant**. In case your instance or its availability zone goes down, you can loose all the users data. The issue with limited storage you are already aware of.

Thus, a **good practice** is to design your application to be **stateless**, which means that it can run on any instance in any availability zone at any time. This requires user files to be stored outside of your instance. The common choices are **S3 and EFS**. The use of any of them will make your application's storage highly available, fault tolerant and scalable.

Comment: But how would you do if you don't want to use S3 and EFS? Would you mount some kind of nfs storage, store the path of the user data inside your database and add more nfs mounts if needed?

Comment: @Olovskos EFS is AWS-managed nfs. But if you want to host your own NFS on some instance with EBS volume then you can also do it. You can increase EBS volume size when you need it up to max 16TB. You can setup RAID 0 using 2 volumes if you need more space.